# Why would structuredClone() ignore properties?

Tags: javascript, axios, structured-clone

In a TypeScript web project I am using [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) to deep-clone an `AxiosError` object from the Axios library, defined as:

```js
export interface AxiosError<T = any> extends Error {
  //...
  isAxiosError: boolean;
  toJSON: () => object;
}

interface Error {
    name: string;
    // ...
}
```

My code:

```js
function f(axiosError: AxiosError<ArrayBuffer>): void {
  const copy = window.structuredClone(axiosError);
  const a = typeof axiosError.name === "undefined";         // false
  const b = typeof axiosError.isAxiosError === "undefined"; // false
  const c = typeof copy.name === "undefined";               // false
  const d = typeof copy.isAxiosError === "undefined";       // true
}
```

Upon further investigation, it appears that all of the parent properties are cloned, but the child properties are not. Why? I can reproduce this in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Are you able to successfully clone an instance of the `AxiosError` class? [Here's a reproducible example](https://jsfiddle.net/L2vmt56d/) which fails to clone for me (using Chrome v`109.0.5414.119`): it throws a `DOMException` instead.

Comment: Yes, otherwise I could not have made the observations about the missing properties. The error `DataCloneError: Function object could not be cloned` is familiar to me, however. I think I got that when I had tried to directly deep-clone `axiosError.response`. But that was also strange because I could not find a function object inside.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227478/why-would-structuredclone-ignore-properties?noredirect=1#comment132748580_75227478) Hmm... so, to be clear, what console output do you see in the example I shared and what is your browser + version?

Comment: When I run your example on jsfiddle.net, the clone fails. I have Firefox 109.0 and Chrome 109.0.5414.75.

Comment: By "parent" and "child properties" you refer to the two interfaces respectively?

Comment: Does axios `extend` the native `Error` class? I doubt you can clone those.

Comment: I’m guessing, it’s `window`, not “windows”

Comment: @Bergi yes you can, now. It used to be impossible but sending such an Error through `postMessage` was so common that [it's been added to the specs](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4268), though cloning a sub-classed Error like that would only return a basic `Error` out of it.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Yes, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's what I'm referring to. And yes, it's the native error class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking why your sub-classed `AxiosError` only contains the default properties of the parent `Error` class, that's by design.

`structuredClone` is meant to be used to send data across realms. The receiving realm may have no clue about your `AwesomeError` class, and so the object is normalized to what all realms will know about, here an `Error`, but the same applies to other cloneable interfaces like `Set`, `Map` etc.

So indeed, if you stucture clone an instance of a subclass of `Error`, all you get are the default properties of `Error`.

Note that there is [this issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5665) which aims to at least make `.name` be treated exceptionally in the cloning algo, but it still requires implementers interest (read, "it's not done yet").

Comment: Correct. I find this very surprising though, and I don't understand the reasoning behind it - after all, you can `structuredClone` other custom objects, and the function docs mention nothing that suggests it is not a generally applicable function. But it is what its is.

Comment: I've created a [little demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CiUoHsrIQAekIAJgM7LZ4EDeAUMsjLrgFzIVhSgDmDAL4MGCADZwKVDDXyYSEcv0ILyVWfSYs2yALzIARK1wGtuAG7ReZFCDgBbFPoMyc+U8NESpaLG6gAkvYADmIQjuDKwCFhEWDq-siMzMZ6hsamzHaOaS5+tJnIjlJwfE6GHiIIuCDcRflyqmT8AMJiNeXcUACuCGDdUBBkbR0AFCAQAO6+GvKkzSB8owCUy6I1dfYNgTHhimCt7RNpXb39g8NHEONTM-5BoXuRiytr67W4YQB07UsABsZdAASOhbWZNQ4dL7GQTIbIQYGg7ZzRQLPgjCZfeGCP5raofb6-UYAtiIsH3XZxSGYmFwhwIkHk2gPWL7akQLH0nFrIA).

Comment: "you can `structuredClone` other custom objects". You mean bare `Object` instances, right? If you do `class Foo { constructor() { this.own = "own" } get common(){ return "common"; } }; const instance = new Foo(); Object.defineProperty(instance, "ownget", { get(){ return Math.random(); }, enumerable: true }); const copy = structuredClone(instance)` `copy` will not be an instance of `Foo`,  but a bare `Object`. It won't have access to `Foo`'s `common` getter, but it will have its `own` property set, and even its `ownget` one, though it will not be a getter anymore, but just a value.

Comment: The same happens with other classes that can be cloned. `Error` is one such class, that has its own cloning steps because we want that an `Error`  from a realm still be an `Error` in another realm. Just like we want an `Array` in a realm to still have its `.length` to work after its been cloned. However all the properties that came from your custom subclass can't be cloned to another realm, since that subclass may not exist there.